# App Works in Flash but not on my website

Tags: php, actionscript-3, amfphp

Ok, so I'm having this problem with an application I wrote in AS3 and PHP (Linked together using AMFPHP) and What happens is (Using a basic way of saying it) I retrieve data from a database and display it on the screen. I've done this many times before and it works on both the web and in Flash Pro. itself. The problem I'm having this time is that it works perfectly in Flash Pro. but when I upload it to my web host, it doesn't work and it shows a blank screen. Any suggestions? If you require any additional information please ask, thanks a million!

Comment: Have you tried calling the php script on the web host directly via the browser without flash ? what does it return ? Is it the data you expect it to return ?

Answer (score 0):

Blank screen sounds like the html/javascript that loads the swf is bad.

I would look into the URLS and make sure they are all valid.

Also look for no JavaScript errors.